# Element inheriting style from parent, even when explicitly defined otherwise

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've got a two-tiered navigation menu. Using the CSS `:hover` class, I've hidden the sub-navigation menus until you hover over the appropriate parent. For some reason, the text styling of the sub-navigation menus are the same as the parent navigation, even though I've explicitly added a rule otherwise. Can someone explain what I've done wrong?

In short: why is my `nav.sub_navigation menuitem a` selector not being applied as I intended?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvxgxtn/).

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="main_navigation">

    <menuitem><a href="">Articles</a></menuitem>
    <nav class="sub_navigation">
        <menuitem><a href="">All</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Programming</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Security</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Design</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Productivity</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Miscellaneous</a></menuitem>
    </nav>

    <menuitem><a href="">About</a></menuitem>
    <nav class="sub_navigation">
        <menuitem><a href="">Biography</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Freelancing</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Resume</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Contact Information</a></menuitem>
    </nav>

    <menuitem><a href="">Projects</a></menuitem>
    <nav class="sub_navigation">
        <menuitem><a href="">Gallery</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Current Work</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Side Projects</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a href="">Github Repositories</a></menuitem>
    </nav>

</nav>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
nav#main_navigation {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    text-align: center;
}

nav#main_navigation menuitem a {
    padding: 0 12px;
    color: #a40003;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

nav#main_navigation menuitem a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}

nav.sub_navigation {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
}

nav.sub_navigation menuitem a {
    padding: 0 7px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav.sub_navigation menuitem a:hover {
    color: #003351;
}

/* to show the appropriate sub-navigation */
nav#main_navigation menuitem:hover + nav.sub_navigation {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `menuitem` is not supported by most broswers.

Comment: it could just as easily be a `div` tag, and i'm only targeting one browser. is `menuitem` what's causing the problem? if that were the case, wouldn't it fail to style the main navigation?

Comment: Dunno...but, it's not being used in the right context, see:  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-menuitem-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the rules to the directly underlying children: `nav#main_navigation > menuitem > a` and `nav.sub_navigation > menuitem > a`

You're using an id in your `main_navigation` rule, that's why it is more concrete, resulting in a [higher priority](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm) and overwrites the `sub_navigation` rule.

Comment: This worked, and also solves a problem I had with the fly-out. Thank you.